# how to create json from key value pair of array in angular2

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

```
    "dynaModel": [
{
  "map": {
    "UNIT/SUBUNIT": "EAS",
    "SUBUNIT/ISU/GEO": "Africa",
    "'APR-16'_REVENUEUSD-$": "$805,298",
    "'APR-16'_COSTUSD-$": "$701,026",
    "'APR-16'_GMINR-RSUSD-$": 12.95,
    "'Total'_REVENUEUSD-$": "$805,298",
    "'Total'_COSTUSD-$": "$701,026",
    "'Total'_GMINR-RSUSD-$": 12.95
  }
},
{
  "map": {
    "UNIT/SUBUNIT": "fgdfg",
    "SUBUNIT/ISU/GEO": "dfgdfg",
    "'APR-16'_REVENUEUSD-$": "$58,",
    "'APR-16'_COSTUSD-$": "$32,",
    "'APR-16'_GMINR-RSUSD-$": 43.98,
    "'Total'_REVENUEUSD-$": "$58,",
    "'Total'_COSTUSD-$": "$32,",
    "'Total'_GMINR-RSUSD-$": 43
  }
},
```

....
.....

How to convert it into the following below format using angular 2

```
   output= [
    {
     "UNIT/SUBUNIT": "hjgh",
    "SUBUNIT/ISU/GEO": "ghjg",
    "'APR-16'_REVENUEUSD-$": "$805",
    "'APR-16'_COSTUSD-$": "$70",
    "'APR-16'_GMINR-RSUSD-$": 12.95,
    "'Total'_REVENUEUSD-$": "$80",
    "'Total'_COSTUSD-$": "$701",
    "'Total'_GMINR-RSUSD-$": 12
},
{
  "UNIT/SUBUNIT": "jjghjhj",
    "SUBUNIT/ISU/GEO": "hjgh",
    "'APR-16'_REVENUEUSD-$": "$58,",
    "'APR-16'_COSTUSD-$": "$32,",
    "'APR-16'_GMINR-RSUSD-$": 43.98,
    "'Total'_REVENUEUSD-$": "$58,0",
    "'Total'_COSTUSD-$": "$32,",
    "'Total'_GMINR-RSUSD-$": 43.98
},
```

..
..
..

];

I am recently tried as follows
 I extract key value pair from the first json file using following code and then push each pair in the jsonObject array.

```
  jsonObject = []; 

  for(let isugeo of this.responseStatus.dynaModel){     
     for( let isugeomap of this.generateArray(isugeo.map)){
       this.jsonObject.push(isugeomap.key+':'+"'" +isugeomap.value+"'");       
     }    console.log('Request Completed' + 
    JSON.stringify(this.jsonObject));
    };


    generateArray(responseStatus){
     return Object.keys(responseStatus).map((key) => { return {key:key, value:responseStatus[key]}});
 }
```

but it doesn't give me the correct format any help how i will proceed

Answer (score 2):

I would use the js map method (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
let output = this.responseStatus.dynaModel.map(item => item.map);
```

Answer (score 1):

`dynaModel` is an array of objects so you can loop throuh it and pick `map` property (which is an object also) of every object in and put that object into `output` array.

```
let response = {
  "dynaModel": [
    {
      "map": {
        "UNIT/SUBUNIT": "EAS",
        "SUBUNIT/ISU/GEO": "Africa",
        "'APR-16'_REVENUEUSD-$": "$805,298",
        "'APR-16'_COSTUSD-$": "$701,026",
        "'APR-16'_GMINR-RSUSD-$": 12.95,
        "'Total'_REVENUEUSD-$": "$805,298",
        "'Total'_COSTUSD-$": "$701,026",
        "'Total'_GMINR-RSUSD-$": 12.95
      }
    },
    {
      "map": {
        "UNIT/SUBUNIT": "fgdfg",
        "SUBUNIT/ISU/GEO": "dfgdfg",
        "'APR-16'_REVENUEUSD-$": "$58,",
        "'APR-16'_COSTUSD-$": "$32,",
        "'APR-16'_GMINR-RSUSD-$": 43.98,
        "'Total'_REVENUEUSD-$": "$58,",
        "'Total'_COSTUSD-$": "$32,",
        "'Total'_GMINR-RSUSD-$": 43
      }
    }
  ]
}

let output = new Array();

for (let object of response.dynaModel) {
  output.push(object.map);
}

console.log(output);
```

prints:

```
[ { 'UNIT/SUBUNIT': 'EAS',
'SUBUNIT/ISU/GEO': 'Africa',
'\'APR-16\'_REVENUEUSD-$': '$805,298',
'\'APR-16\'_COSTUSD-$': '$701,026',
'\'APR-16\'_GMINR-RSUSD-$': 12.95,
'\'Total\'_REVENUEUSD-$': '$805,298',
'\'Total\'_COSTUSD-$': '$701,026',
'\'Total\'_GMINR-RSUSD-$': 12.95 },
{ 'UNIT/SUBUNIT': 'fgdfg',
'SUBUNIT/ISU/GEO': 'dfgdfg',
'\'APR-16\'_REVENUEUSD-$': '$58,',
'\'APR-16\'_COSTUSD-$': '$32,',
'\'APR-16\'_GMINR-RSUSD-$': 43.98,
'\'Total\'_REVENUEUSD-$': '$58,',
'\'Total\'_COSTUSD-$': '$32,',
'\'Total\'_GMINR-RSUSD-$': 43 } ]
```